# how the word "car" is related with the word "driver"

Tags: computational-linguistics, lexical-relations

how the word "car" is related with the word "driver?" I was looking through the list of relationship terms like hyponym, hypernym, part-of, consist-of. But this is a relationship that one is operating on the other. I figured that there may exist a precise technical term for such relationship. And more importantly, by using NLP software, how can I find a list of words such relationship. e.g., given the word "car," how can I use the NLP to get a list words like "driver" "gas" "parking lot" "traffic" "speeding" "crash" etc.

Many thanks in advance. I'm new to NLP so my question sounds silly. Will work hard on that :-)